# How to overwrite a function used in a module-method?

Tags: perl, function, methods, module, overwrite

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use utf8;

use WWW::Mechanize::Cached;
use Some::Module qw(some_method);

my $url = '...';
my $result = some_method( $url );
```

The `some_method()` uses itself `get()` form `LWP::Simple`.
How could I overwrite the `get()` with my `my_get()` in this script?

```
sub my_get {
    my $url;
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Cached->new();
    $mech->get( $url );
    my $content = $mech->content( format => 'text' );
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sub WWW::Mechanize::Cached::get {
    # your code
}
```

OR, if the `get` method is actually, as you imply in the question, is inherited from LWP::Simple -

```
sub LWP::Simple::get {
    # your code
}
```

Comment: Make sure you load the module you want to override before you do this, and you might want a `no warnings 'redefine'`. I talk about this stuff extensively in _Mastering Perl_. There's a whole chapter on just this question. :)